# Winforms Application Template

Tags: winforms, templates

I am trying to create a Winforms application with a generic template i.e. all the forms will inherit a predefined template for new, save, edit, delete buttons and some generic images and rest of the stuff I will put manually of inheriting forms.

Any suggestions how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a new form as the template-like one and force it to implement an interface, in my sample below I named that interface `IApplicationWindow`, with the declaration of the common methods that are intended to be implemented by the sub-classes.

I would also place in the template-like form, in addition to the common controls you mention,  all the stuff that should be commonly used along all windows like logging helper classes and so on.

Assuming that we've defined already an interface named `IApplicationWindow`, a template-like form would look like this:

```
public partial class TemplateForm : Form, IApplicationWindow
{
    // Place here as protected class members all object instances
    // that are common to all your forms, like helper class for logging
    // purposes or security delegates.
    [...]

    public TemplateForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region IApplicationWindow interface implementation

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        // Do nothing unless you need common behavior.
        // Leave extenders implement the concrete behavior.
    }

    public virtual void Edit()
    {
        // Do nothing unless you need common behavior.
        // Leave extenders implement the concrete behavior.
    }

    [...]

    #endregion
}
```

And this is how a form extending the your template-like form would looks like (note that you must override the methods to provide an specific implementation):

```
public partial class AnApplicationWindow : TemplateForm
{
    public AnApplicationWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public override void Save()
    {
        base.Save();
        // Implement specific behavior here
    }

    public override void Edit()
    {
        base.Edit();
        // Implement specific behavior here
    }

    [...]

}
```

Finally I would place carefully the common controls in the UI of the template form so that if you resize the extending forms the controls are placed correclty (use correctly the anchors).